# Java MySQL connetion pool is not working

Tags: java, mysql, apache-commons

I've written a function in Java that runs a MySQL query and returns results. I've implemented connection pooling using this method here: http://www.kodejava.org/how-do-i-create-a-database-connection-pool/. The function is working, but connection time is still the same as it was without pooling ~190 ms. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> query(String q) throws Exception {

    long start, end;

    GenericObjectPool connectionPool = null;

    String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname";
    String USER = "root";
    String PASS = "";

    Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();

    connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool();
    connectionPool.setMaxActive(10);

    ConnectionFactory cf = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(URL, USER, PASS);

    PoolableConnectionFactory pcf = new PoolableConnectionFactory(cf, connectionPool, null, null, false, true);

    DataSource ds = new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);

    //create statement
    Statement Stm = null;

    try {

        Connection Con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Con = ds.getConnection();

        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("DB Connection: " + Long.toString(end - start) + " ms");

        //fetch out rows
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> Rows = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

        Stm = Con.createStatement();

        //query
        ResultSet Result = null;

        boolean Returning_Rows = Stm.execute(q);

        if (Returning_Rows) {
            Result = Stm.getResultSet();
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        }

        //get metadata
        ResultSetMetaData Meta = null;
        Meta = Result.getMetaData();

        //get column names
        int Col_Count = Meta.getColumnCount();
        ArrayList<String> Cols = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int Index=1; Index<=Col_Count; Index++) {
            Cols.add(Meta.getColumnName(Index));
        }

        while (Result.next()) {
            HashMap<String,Object> Row = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            for (String Col_Name:Cols) {
                Object Val = Result.getObject(Col_Name);
                Row.put(Col_Name,Val);
            }
            Rows.add(Row);
        }

        //close statement
        Stm.close();


        //pass back rows
        return Rows;

    } catch (Exception Ex) {

        System.out.print(Ex.getMessage());
        return new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

    } finally {

        if (Stm != null) {
            Stm.close();
        }
        if (Stm != null) {
            Stm.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Max connections: " + connectionPool.getMaxActive());
        System.out.println("Active connections: " + connectionPool.getNumActive());
        System.out.println("Idle connections: " + connectionPool.getNumIdle());

    }

}
```

This is console output every time:

```
DB Connection: 186 ms
Max connections: 10 
Active connections: 1 
Idle connections: 0
```

**UPDATE:** I should note, that Java application that uses this works like this: executes, only runs one query and closes. I figured if PHP works like this and it's using connection pooling by default, so should Java? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Once again, there's no need to create a connection pool for a run-once application. If you just hold on to a reference of a single connection, that's a connection pool of size 1. I think you are obsessing over a 200ms difference between the performance of a PHP page and your own Java application.

Comment: Problem is, that it is highly used application, I'm talking it will run every time anyone loads any page on a big system... hundreds of thousands of times a day. I want to shave off those 200ms which are wasted completely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP vs Java MySQL connection pooling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105989/php-vs-java-mysql-connection-pooling)

Answer (score 2):

You create a connection pool, but you don't put anything into it. You connection pool is empty when it is created, so your first request to it is guaranteed to to create a new connection and will be just as slow as getting a connection manually.

Try putting your code into a loop, where you repeatedly get a connection from the pool. Try it once, five times, ten times and fifteen times. Note how the results change.

Some connection pools support automatically creating and holding a *minimum* number of connections ready for use as well as a *maximum*. When the pool is initialised it will pre-fetch connections so the first few calls aren't delayed.

Comment: Problem is, that application only runs one query, I've explained more in my "UPDATE".

Answer (score 0):

You will not see a difference with a single request to the DB. You have to test this this with multiple (concurrent) requests.

And BTW: You you obeye the Java naming convention and start all objects with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Your can pre-load your pool by calling `connectionPool.addObject()`. At the start it is empty and creates a connection only after you've posted a query.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case does not warrant a connection pool. Its just one connection you need.
The pool class you are using `GenericObjectPool` has a method [`addObject();`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#addObject%28%29). This will create and add the objects to the pool. This will avoid creating connection later.