# PHP vs Java MySQL connection pooling

Tags: java, php, mysql, connection-pooling

I have a problem that thought I will break down to the simplest. There two applications on LAMP stack, one PHP and another Java that do the only and exactly the same thing: run a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

PHP execution takes **30 ms** in total

Java excution takes  **230 ms** in total

Query run on a local MySQL client takes **10-15 ms** in total

Java takes **~200 ms** roughly every time only to establish a connection to the db. I understand that PHP uses some kind of built in connection pooling, therefor it doesn't need to establish a new connection every time and only takes **30 ms** as a result of it.

Is the same thing possible on Java? So far I failed to achieve that. I tried to use Apache Commons DBCP connection pooling, no change at all, still takes the same time to connect to the database.

**UPDATE:** This is a separate question where I'm trying to make connection pooling work on Java, for those who are asking for a code example: [Java MySQL connetion pool is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103852/java-mysql-connetion-pool-is-not-working)

Comment: PHP doesn't use connection pooling (unless you explicitly enable it which has its own issues.). But it can establish connections very quickly. How are you running the code in each case?

Comment: PHP does not implement *real* connection pooling but [persistant connections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) (I still regard this as a very primitive form of connection pooling, but this view is disputed). Please post your test code, you might be misusing the pool. I don't think it should take that long to get a connection from a pool.

Comment: @datasage So what you're saying is that Java can't possibly establish a connection as fast as PHP can, this is a dead end? What do you mean how I'm running the code?

Comment: @Caballero, try getting a second connection through Java and see how long that takes.

Comment: @RandomSeed I've posted a separate question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103852/java-mysql-connetion-pool-is-not-working

Comment: you could use something like codepad or pastebin to show us the source code you are using for these tests, maybe someone will come  up with an idea (maybe an improvement for the java version)

Comment: @Caballero There may be more going on than what meets the eye. Java does often have a startup time that php doesn't have, but once its running its very fast. More information about your code and how you are running your tests would be helpful.

Comment: Is you application a web-application running on an application server? Or is it a stand-alone application?

Comment: @mishu This is an example of my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103852/java-mysql-connetion-pool-is-not-working

Comment: @RandomSeed my java application is standalone.

Comment: @datasage I have specifically measured the time it takes for java to establish a connection. It's always around 200ms.

Comment: You are always getting the same connection time because the pool is closed when your application terminates. You need to call `DataSource::getConnection()` **several** times before getting any benefit from a pool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the concept and purpose of connection pooling.

Connection pooling is meant to maintain a (set of) connections on a single (Java Virtual) machine (typically, an application server). The goal is to allow multiple threads on the same machine to essentially share their connection to the database server without the need to open one everytime they need to query the database.

Stand-alone applications cannot share connections as they run on different Java Virtual Machines, or perhaps even on different physical machines.

Connection pooling would help in your stand-alone application if you had several threads making concurrent access to the database.

However, you can still measure the benefit of connection pooling by wrapping your test (the code inside your `try...catch`) in a loop and iterating a few times. At the first iteration, the connection needs to be opened. Don't forget to release the connection (call `Con.close()`), then it would be reused at the next iteration.